# Powershell: invoke-command с перенаправлением результата

Tags: powershell

Ищу файлы на удаленной машине с перенаправлением результата. Скрипт запускается на windows 10, удаленные машины windows 7.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName comp1 -ScriptBlock {ls -Path c:\ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Include *.avi -Recurse -Force } > out.txt

 Throws an exception type "System.OutOfMemoryException".
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], OutOfMemoryException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.OutOfMemoryException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
+ PSComputerName        : comp1
```

Причем поиск по дискам D: или E: без проблем.
На другом компьютере ситуация повторяется - поиск на диске C: вызывает исключение, а на других дисках нет. Ясно, что переполняется некий буфер.
Что делать, или как обойти проблему?

Comment: Use **stackoverflow.com** instead ru.stackoverflow.com. Здесь вам только на русском помогут (russian language).

Comment: Покажите вывод `dir WSMan:\localhost\Plugin\microsoft.powershell\Quotas` и `dir WSMan:\localhost\Shell` на удалённых компьютерах.

Comment: @PetSerAl, for Windows 7 its microsoft.powershell.workflow instead of microsoft.powershell. WSMan:\localhost\Plugin\microsoft.powershell.workflow\Quotas

Comment: @KirillPashkov Нет, `microsoft.powershell` — это имя по умолчанию для обычных PowerShell подключений, а `microsoft.powershell.workflow` для Workflow PowerShell подключений.